# Speed of associative array (map) in STL

Tags: c++, stl

Wrote a simple program to measure the speed of STL. The following code showed that it took 1.49sec on my Corei7-2670QM PC (2.2GHz and turbo 3.1GHz).  If I remove the `Employees[buf] = i%1000;` part in the loop, it only took 0.0132sec. So the hashing part took 1.48sec.  Why is it that slow?

```
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
using namespace std;

extern "C" {
int get(map<string, int> e, char* s){
    return e[s];
}
int set(map<string, int> e, char* s, int value) {
    e[s] = value;
}
}

double getTS() {
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    return tv.tv_sec + tv.tv_usec/1000000.0;
}

int main()
{
    map<string, int> Employees;
    char buf[10];
    int i;
    double ts = getTS();
    for (i=0; i<1000000; i++) {
        sprintf(buf, "%08d", i);
        Employees[buf] = i%1000;
    }
    printf("took %f sec\n", getTS() - ts);
    cout << Employees["00001234"] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That line is filling the map. Without it, not much is going on.

Comment: Please don't use gettimeofday() for benchmarking.  It's too imprecise !!!  Please tell us which compiler and if you debut in release or debug mode.

Comment: If you remove that line: 1) you end up measuring the time it takes to do nothing (it takes very little time; how surprising!), and 2) the program has undefined behaviour when it accesses the map at the end.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I missed the UB. Where is it?

Comment: @juanchopanza *if you remove that line [...]* `cout << Employees["00001234"] << endl;` is UB

Comment: @Borgleader Why? It is perfectly defined. It evaluates to 0 (`int()`.)

Comment: By the way, adding data to a map using sorted indices, is not a good measurement of performance of the structure.  Indices in a random order would be a better measurement.

Comment: @juanchopanza oh, you're right. My bad. Point #1 stands, though.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I knew gettimeofday() doesn't have the highest precision, but I figure it's at least accurate to millisec, which is good enough.     Concerning the overhead of the for loop and sprintf(..),  (as mentioned in the question) I did the test by commenting out `Employees[buf] = i%1000;` and it took only 0.0132sec.  So it proves `Employees[buf] =  i%1000;` is still pretty slow.  Which is a surprise.  Wish there is an good explanation.

Comment: You are comparing the time it takes to do something against the time it takes to do nothing. Something takes longer.

Comment: Was trying to find out how much time `Employees[buf] = i%1000;` would take on my CPU. Had hoped that it would take 100ns, but it ended up taking about 1400ns (1.4us).    Sorry didn't state the purpose clearly.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews what would be the best way to construct a `std::map` if we have a sorted list of key-value pairs already?

Comment: consider just using the `int` as the map key? it seems likely to me that the majority of the time is spent doing 1 million separate heap allocations of a std::string for the key.

Comment: If the data rarely changes, insert the pairs into a vector, sort it by the first member of the pair, and then use `std::binary_search` etc. so long as you keep the vector sorted after any insertions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notion of *"slow"* depends of course in comparison to what.

I ran your benchmark (using the standard `chrono::high_resolution_clock` instead of gettimeofday() ) on MSVC2013 with release configuration on an Corei7-920 at 2.67 GHz and find very similar results (1.452 s).

In your code, you do basically 1 millions of:

- insertion in the map:  [`Employees\[buf\]`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator%5B%5D/)
- update in the map (copying a new element to exisitng element): `= i%1000`

SO I tried to understand better where the time is spent:

- first, the [map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) needs to store the ordered keys, which is typically implemented with a binary tree. So I tried to use an [unordered_map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/) which uses a flatter hash table and gave it a very large bucket size to avoid clisions and rehashing. The result is then 1.198 s.
  So roughly **20% of the time (here) is needed for making possibile a sorted access** to the map data (i.e. you can iterate through your map using the order of the keys:  do you need this ?)
- next, playing with the order of insertion can really influence significantly the timing. As  *Thomas Matthews pointed* out in the comments: for benchmarking purpose you should use random order.
- then, making only and optimised insertion of data (no search no update) using [`emplace_hint()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/emplace_hint/) brings us to a time of 1.100 s.
  So **75% of the time is needed to allocate and insert the data**
- finally, elaborating on the previous test, if you add an additional search and update after `emplace_hint()`, then the time goes up slightly above the original time (1.468 s).  This confirms that access to the map is only a fraction of the time and most of the execution time is needed for the insertion.

Here the test for the point above:

```
chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point ts = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
for (i = 0; i<1000000; i++) {
    sprintf(buf, "%08d", i);
    Employees.emplace_hint(Employees.end(), buf, 0);
    Employees[buf] = i % 1000;  // matters for 300 
}
chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point te = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
cout << "took " << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(te - ts).count() << " millisecs\n";
```

Now your benchmark not only depends performance of the map:  you do 1 million of `sprintf()` to set your buffer, and 1 million of conversion to a string. If you'd use a map instead,  you'd notice that the whole test would take only 0.950s instead of 1.450s:

- **30%  of your benchmark time is caused not by the map, but by the many strings you handle !**

Of course, all this is much slower than a vector.  But a vector doesn't sort its elements, and cannot provide for associative store.

Comment: Well, if we're optimizing... Since all the insertions are unique and ordered, here's my take **[Live On Coliru](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28549938/85371)** being over 3x faster (compared to my own earlier version)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a C++ version of your code. Note that you should ***obviously*** take the maps by reference when passing them in `get`/`set`.

**UPDATE** Taking things a bit further and seriously optimizing for the given test case:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1ac42f3456d68607)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/container/flat_map.hpp>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;

using Map = boost::container::flat_map<string, int>;

int get(Map &e, char *s) { return e[s]; }
int set(Map &e, char *s, int value) { return e[s] = value; }

using Clock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;

template <typename F, typename Reso = std::chrono::microseconds, typename... Args> 
Reso measure(F&& f, Args&&... args) {
    auto since = Clock::now();
    std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    return chrono::duration_cast<Reso>(Clock::now() - since);
}

#include <boost/iterator/iterator_facade.hpp>

using Pair = std::pair<std::string, int>;

struct Gen : boost::iterators::iterator_facade<Gen, Pair, boost::iterators::single_pass_traversal_tag, Pair>
{
    int i;
    Gen(int i = 0) : i(i) {}

    value_type dereference() const { 
        char buf[10];
        std::sprintf(buf, "%08d", i);
        return { buf, i%1000 }; 
    }
    bool equal(Gen const& o) const { return i==o.i; }
    void increment() { ++i; }
};

int main() {
    Map Employees;
    const auto n = 1000000;

    auto elapsed = measure([&] {
            Employees.reserve(n);
            Employees.insert<Gen>(boost::container::ordered_unique_range, {0}, {n});
        });

    std::cout << "took " << elapsed.count() / 1000000.0 << " sec\n";

    cout << Employees["00001234"] << endl;
}
```

Prints

```
took 0.146575 sec
234
```

---

#### *Old answer*

This just used C++ where appropriate

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3fda521534200474)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int get(map<string, int>& e, char* s){
    return e[s];
}
int set(map<string, int>& e, char* s, int value) {
    return e[s] = value;
}

using Clock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;

template <typename Reso = std::chrono::microseconds>
Reso getElapsed(Clock::time_point const& since) {
    return chrono::duration_cast<Reso>(Clock::now() - since);
}

int main()
{
    map<string, int> Employees;
    std::string buf(10, '\0');

    auto ts = Clock::now();
    for (int i=0; i<1000000; i++) {
        buf.resize(std::sprintf(&buf[0], "%08d", i));
        Employees[buf] = i%1000;
    }
    std::cout << "took " << getElapsed(ts).count()/1000000.0 << " sec\n";
    cout << Employees["00001234"] << endl;
}
```

Prints:

```
took 0.470009 sec
234
```

Comment: On what kind of machine do you get this result ?  With similar config than OP, I get 1.430s so slightly better than original timing (thanks to your good idea to sprint directly into the (c++) string)

Comment: There are other benchmarking crimes in this code that aren't included- for example, the performance of the local stdlib implementation of std::string and std::sprintf, and the compiler can even legally `std::cout << took` before calling `Clock::now()`. So I wouldn't put too much stock in this result.

Comment: It's not about the benchmarking at all. it's about the code style, for me.

Comment: Added a version that does care about optimizing. As always, optimizations hinge much more on the choice of algorithms/datastructures than anything else. (Of course the strings are the bottleneck here.) /cc @Puppy

Comment: Actually, taking advantage of the fixed-length keys, you can use `std::array<char, 8>` as the key. See **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/42c640c273d3f914)**